# C# Resize textbox to fit content using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having a program where there will be notes in the textbox. I'd like the textbox to resize itself, so it fit the content.

[image]

```
 private void rg_pending_RowFormatting(object sender, RowFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            which code i will place here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font);
textBox1.Width = size.Width;
textBox1.Height = size.Height;
```

Comment: i am using grid view

Comment: Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.RowElement.Text, rg_pending.Font);

            e.RowElement.RowInfo.Height = size.Height;

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: if gridview, then you need to paste your script, in order to know your issue exactly,